# CodeIgniter keeping session alive via session_time_to_update

Tags: codeigniter, session

I want to keep sessions alive for an extended period of time for peoples shopping carts, and was wondering if its a good idea to do so by setting the session_time_to_update variable in the config file to the desired time (i.e. 6 months).

I changed it to 7200 seconds at the moment and can see that I am still logged in after 5 minutes (it was 300 seconds by default).

Comment: I would advise using the native php sessions class & use cookies to store the session id for a shopping cart as the current codeigniter's session has a limit of like 4K or less (only cookies are used). but if it's working for you, then your solution is OK.

Comment: @ahmad Thanks, I've only tested it for a login, not the actual cart. Is 4K not big enough to store the contents of a shopping cart?

Comment: If your cookies are encrypted (they better be!), 4K is not a huge amount of data to work with. That said, if you just hold onto an array of product ids, you should be fine.

Comment: Depends on what you store in the session, it's a cookie limitation, that's why I prefer using native php sessions where I only store the session id in the cookie & the rest would be stored in the server inside a file.

Comment: Enable CI database session, that way you can store as much as you want in the session as the cookie will not go above 4KB since it will only contain the session id, (optionally: useragent, and IP), the rest of the session information including products, etc will be stored in database table.